# Wordpress upload image error

Tags: wordpress, image-uploading

I've built a wordpress website on my mamp localhost, and subsequently uploaded it to a web hosting service.

Since I've uploaded it I cannot upload images via the wordpress 'add media' section. I temporarily change the 'uploads' permissions to 777 and it solved the problem.

I know 777 isn't best practise so I changed it back to 755 and the error has reoccurred.

Is this something to do with the admin user and password I originally set up for wordpress on my localhost versus the ftp user which I created and used to upload the site to the web hosting service?

Does the ftp user own the files - therefore stopping the wordpress admin user from uploading files?

Thanks

Comment: Use 775 if 755 won't work. You do not need to do anything with your wordpress of ftp user. It's related to (i guess) linux user/group.

Comment: Should I set it to 755 for folders only? - or files and folders?

Comment: Files should be 644, directories should be 755. This is a owner:group issue, permissions issue. Read more in [Hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress).

Comment: You most likely need to `chown -R username:groupname` your apache user/group.

Comment: Mevius - Can I do this chown procedure using Filezilla?

Comment: I contacted my web host and they did what Mevius suggested - it fixed the problem, thanks.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer, so this question can be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files should be 644, directories should be 755. This is an owner:group permissions issue. Read more in [Hardening WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress).

The real issue is an ownership issue. You're going to need to `chown -R username:groupname` to your Apache user/group, so that WordPress can write to these directories.

Answer (score 0):

chown -R username:groupname your apache user/group fixed the problem.